# Rails file loading?/module including

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to set up helper in `app/helpers`path.

So, for test purpose, I did this:

```
#app/helpers/somehelper.rb
class SomeHelper
  def some
    return true
  end
end
```

I included this line in one of my controllers:

```
test=SomeHelper.new
```

That raises `uninitialized constant SomeHelper` error.

I tried 2 things:

In `cofing/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/helpers/**/"]
```

Didn't work.

Then I tried this:

In `application_controller`

```
 include SomeHelper
```

Still getting error.

How do I load helper (or any other folder) into my application load path?

Comment: It's either that you should name the file some_helper.rb or you should restart the server...

Comment: the include is not necessary  and I think the helpers are autoloaded. BTW, in Rails all helpers are modules. So you could consider putting those PORO's in a seperate dir, as long as they are a child of the /app directory, they will be autoloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to manually include or autoload anything, rails uses naming conventions to locate and load the file for you.

When rails encounters a new class, in your case `SomeHelper`, it will automatically attempt to load `some_helper.rb`

So all you have to do is put an underscore in the file name of your helper:

```
#app/helpers/some_helper.rb
```

Comment: Don't forget that SomeHelper also needs to be a module